# Simple covariance problem:

Tags: regression, least-squares

OLS population estimator can be derived by running the coverience operator throught the model:

cov (y,x)= acov (1,x) +b cov (x,x) +cov(u,x)
the estimator requires cov(u,x)=cov(1,x)=0.

Explain why one can write cov (1,x)=0

(useing the definition of the coverence (cov(W,Z)=E[ ... etc

Comment: The algebra is extremely simple: have you attempted to work it out?  All you need to know is how to multiply by $1.$

Comment: I have tried: Cov(1,x)= E{[(1-E(1)][x-E(x)]}=E(1x)-E(1)E(x) Is this all I need to do to show it ?

Comment: That ought to do it.